# How many addition operations are being performed by np.sum()?

Tags: python, numpy

Lets consider I have an array of shape `(1, 3, 4, 4)` and I apply `numpy.sum()` on this and reduce against `axes [2,3]`. Below is a sample code --

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(1, 3, 4, 4)
res = np.sum(data, axis=(2,3), keepdims=True)
```

How many addition operations are being done by `np.sum()`?

Comment: This seems like a really weird question. Did you have some reason to care about the exact quantity, or to believe that it would be anything other than the number performed if you just go through and add up the elements the straightforward way?

Comment: The result is (1,3), so that's 3 sums, each over 16 terms (4x4).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I understand it looks weird. But I am trying to estimate the number of operations it would take for some hardware related simulation.

Comment: @hpaulj Could you please elaborate how did you come up with that number?

Comment: @amitection: This still seems like a really weird question. `numpy.sum` does a lot of things other than element addition operations. Ufunc dispatch, result buffer allocation, dimension handling, chunk copying, etc. Don't you care about those operations? Why are you asking for an exact number of addition operations?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [202]: data = np.arange(3*4*4).reshape(1,3,4,4)
```

do your sum:

```
In [203]: res = np.sum(data, axis=(2,3), keepdims=True)                                                
In [204]: res                                                                                          
Out[204]: 
array([[[[120]],

        [[376]],

        [[632]]]])
In [205]: res.shape                                                                                    
Out[205]: (1, 3, 1, 1)
```

to produce each of the 3 sums:

```
In [207]: for i in range(3): 
     ...:     print(data[0,i].sum()) 
     ...:                                                                                              
120
376
632
```

And in a more detailed simulation (for one of those 3):

```
In [208]: tot=0 
     ...: for i in range(4): 
     ...:     for j in range(4): 
     ...:         tot += data[0,0,i,j] 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [209]: tot                                                                                          
Out[209]: 120
```

I'll let you count the `+=`.